# Vertical space only after every second row in a table

Tags: tables, spacing, vertical-alignment, external-files, r

I have several tables in the following custom format, to which I would like to add vertical space (e.g. 6 pt) after every second row. I know this can be done manually. I am only wondering, if there is a process to do this faster. Note that my tables come from external tex.files. So if possible I'd like a solution which can be applied to tables imported via `input` (source: xtable/R). But I am also curious how to do this quickly for normally, in Latex produced tables.

Here is a simple MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline, smallheadings]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\newcolumntype{Y}{D..{-1}}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{aaa} 
{\normalsize
\begin{tabular}{lYYYYY}
\toprule 
& \multicolumn{1}{r}{A} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{C} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{E} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{D} \\
\midrule 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{X} &  0.34  &  0.08^{***} & -2.57^{***} &  0.60^{***} &  80.97 \\ 
& (0.44) & (0.05) & (1.26) & (0.24) &  \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Y} &  0.34  &  0.20^{***} &  0.99^{***} &  0.00^{***}   & 97.71 \\ 
& (1.30) & (1.03) & (0.01) & (0.00) &  \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Z} &  0.56  & 5.41^{***} &  0.08^{***} &  0.98^{***} & 33.27 \\ 
& (1.30) & (2.030) & (0.03) & (0.01) &  \\ 
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

So in the end, I want this table to look as good as possible. Any suggestions appreciated, except for the content/brackets/stars. These must stay. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there's a good way to do this, so I'll suggest a hack and possibly not a particularly good one.  The trick is to alternately replace `\\` with `\crsng` and `\crdbl`.  The former is just equivalent to your old `\\` and the latter is equivalent to your old `\\[6pt]`.

1. Introduce the following before `\begin{tabular}`:

   ```
   \global\let\restorecr=\
   ```
2. Introduce the following after `\toprule`:

   ```
   \global\let\oldcr=\\
   \global\def\crsng{\global\let\\=\crdbl\oldcr}
   \global\def\crdbl{\global\let\\=\crsng\oldcr[6pt]}
   \global\let\\=\crdbl
   ```
3. Introduce the following after `\end{tabular}`:

   ```
   \global\let\\=\restorecr
   ```

You'll probably want to tweak it a little bit, if you don't like what it's doing to the header and the footer of your tabular.

[image: result]

Comment: thanks for the hack. I am waiting a little bit more to see if someone has a different approach, then I'd accept your answer. It doesn't work with external tex files though.

Comment: You mean if you `\input` what's inside your `tabular`?  I can't understand why it shouldn't work.

Comment: I believe it does work, but Texstudio shows errors if you do it that way. It seems to think the part in input is missing. I am leaving this open a little bit, maybe someone has a different solution. But eventually you will get the accept if nothing else shows up in the near future.